# How to increase current capacity of an ideal diode circuit?

Tags: diodes

We know ideal diodes doesn't exist but there are circuits that behave similar to ideal diodes.So my question is.
Can I add two ideal diode circuits in parallel each with 100 Amp current capacity to get a capacity of 200 Amps? These diodes are made from MOSFETs and BJTs. I am using [LTC4371](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4371f.pdf) manufactured by Linear Technology.

Comment: Your title is asking about ideal diodes which don't exist while your question is asking about real components. This is a bit confusing.

Comment: Diodes are NTC devices so bear that in mind

Comment: Current sharing in MOSFETs is usually far from perfect.

Comment: Jet Propulsion Lab (the folks behind those reliable satellites) encountered modern MOSFETs that easily self-destructed because of thermal runaway. OLD_STYLE FETs would self-protect; not the modern FETS. The automobile industry encountered this problem before JPL but remained quiet.

Comment: @Transistor, there is also a real circuit called an "ideal diode".

Comment: @Transistor yes you are right ideal diodes doesn't exist but there are circuits that behave like ideal diode.Here i refer to those circuits

Comment: OK. I suggest that you clarify that in your question. Your readers may not see the comment.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably be better to use large module-type MOSFETs or parallel smaller MOSFETs as shown in the datasheet.

MOSFETs have a high temperature coefficient of Rds(on) so to get them to share better, it's good to have them relatively thermally isolated from each other (ie. individual heat sinks) so the one hogging the current gets hotter, and thus hogs less current.

Using two chips with separate MOSFETs could cause problems as the chip uses a closed-loop controller to maintain constant voltage across the conducting MOSFET and two of them could interact and cause instability.

Comment: The datasheet actually shows a current sharing arrangement for a 50A solution. The MOSFETs are limited by the SOA curve in that application.

Comment: @PeterSmith I didn't say to use the same MOSFETs, just that they could be paralleled as in the datasheet. Of course the MOSFETs have to be appropriate to the current.

Comment: My comment was an observation only :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but you need to take care. In addition the the excellent advice from Spehro, you need to understand the system quite closely.

Here is the standard application from the datasheet:
[image: Standard application]
As you can see, there is a single MOSFET on each channel.

If you look at the MOSFET [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPT020N10N3-DS-v02_00-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30433e9d5d11013e9e58035b0158), you will see this is a 300A device which might seem overkill for a 25A solution, but the real limiting factor is found deeper in the datasheet in the [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_operating_area) graph:
The red arrow points at close to where the MOSFET is operating in this scenario (actually a little further up the current axis):

[image: IPT02010N SOA graph]

That is about as close as I would want to get to the edge where derating would be necessary (which I have not done here).

The datasheet does show a 50A solution using paralleled devices:
[image: LTC4371 50A solution]

As you can see, there are two MOSFETs in parallel in each channel. As there is some margin from the SOA graph, the two can share current somewhat unevenly (I have seen current share mismatch at 40%) and still remain in the safe part of the SOA.

So you can, but  be aware of the limitations of the MOSFETs and use identical MOSFETs for the parallel pair.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a general one, *Can you combine two "Ideal Diode" circuits to double the current capability?*

The suggestion is to use two  LTC4371.

The question is undefined, since the common fault conditions that may cause failure in a redundant design are not provided yet some are treated in the datasheet such as output and input short circuit protection.  The data sheet shows how to increase capacity by adding more parallel devices yet ignores the possibility of choosing FETs with lower RdsOn.

We know that MOSFETS have a PTC characteristic that prevents shunt thermal runaway in current sharing mode, but the reality is that under light loads towards linear saturation operation when Vgs is reduced, MOSFETS can have an NTC characteristic which can result in thermal runaway.
( proof is beyond scope of this question)

Another fact you may not know is that each power MOSFET is actually like thousands of small junctions in parallel each with perhaps slightly different threshold curves.  You wouldn't parallel two devices with different Vgs(th) yet in a dynamic low to high current condition, a small difference in Vgs(th)  can result in an SOA over-stress hotspot.

So when considering scaling up the current capacity of a circuit, ask yourself, is it a constant current design or does it operating in a wide step load range and if any mode of operation is below the PTC/NTC inflection point that make it prone to thermal runaway in hotspots inside one device.

[**This article**](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8199-D.PDF) describes the problem  in constant current mode and a solution using thermal sensing.